# Undo a git rerere resolution that was done in a rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-rerere

Okay, so I really like the `git rerere` command, although I haven't really used it that much other than letting it auto-magically record my conflicts and resolve them for me.  However, I did mess up one of my conflict resolutions during quite a large rebase (rebasing a really stale feature branch with the latest release).

```
feature -> a - b - c - d

release -> e - f - g - h

rebase/feature -> e - f - g - h .
                                 ` a' - b' - c' - d'
```

So, say for instance that `b'` has an incorrect merge (thanks to me!), and I want to re-record that.  How would I do it?  I've seen the `git checkout --conflict` option, mentioned in [Rerere Your Boat](http://git-scm.com/2010/03/08/rerere.html), but I'm not too clear on how that works and if it applies here.  Maybe I have to checkout the merge conflict state and run `git rerere` once I correctly resolve this conflict?

Normally, I would just commit to the tip of the rebase branch, but it is a throw away.  I'm just trying to handle conflicts ahead of time, so that when I sync up with that feature team, we minimize the time it takes.  Make sense?

Comment: Whoever wants to forget all `git rerere` resolutions, the comment by @JánSáreník under http://stackoverflow.com/a/21635422/2816199 can be of tremendous help.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

To simply remove all previous `rerere` resolutions, run `rm -rf .git/rr-cache` to remove the cache.

For a specific merge, you can tell `rerere` to forget the recorded resolution by re-executing the merge and allowing `rerere` to apply its recorded resolution in the work tree.

You can check out `a'` and then do a `git merge b` to get back into that situation (you'll probably be in a checkout of a detached head since you specified the commit hash of `a'`, so be aware that you're not on a branch).

Then use `git rerere forget FILE-WITH-BAD-MERGE` where to specify the file whose recorded conflict resolution should be forgetten.

> `forget <pathspec>`
>   Reset the conflict resolutions which rerere has recorded for the current conflict in .

(From [the Git documentation for git-rerere](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere).)

Comment: You can also do `rm -rf .git/rr-cache` to clean rr cache completely.

Comment: ^^ this helped while `rerere forget` did not do it for me

Comment: The original author was confused by `git checkout --conflict`. However, if you're in the middle of the rebase and don't want to start over, that option is on the right track. There is a more familiar option, `-m`. You can do `git checkout -m FILE-WITH-BAD-MERGE` to restore the file's more familiar, default conflict markers. As if you didn't have rerere's resolution applied in the first place.

Comment: `git checkout -m` and `--conflict` does not always produce a file with conflict markers (as I've just seen): if it succeeds merging the two variants, it shows no conflicts, although the result may be unwanted (from your point of view). Not sure whether `git rerere` records anything at all for such files, so you might not need to forget anything, because the unwanted results comes from another mechanism.

Comment: is `git rerere forget <pathspec>` meant to be used within or outside merge context? I'm getting a no-op outside of merge context and an "error: no remembered resolution for <pathspec>" within merge context. I'm positive there is a remembered resolution for it, b.c. at the start of the merge, it applied recorded resolutions.

Comment: It works a bit confusing, because you first have to do the merge, and the (bad) recorded pre-image will be applied. THEN you have to do remove the recorded pre-image with `git rerere forget <file>`. Then you should `git reset --hard origin/<branch>` to again do the merge from there, and only then you get the original conflict again and you can correct the resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Git cherry-pick supports `--no-rerere-autoupdate` option, that is what I use.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32836928)