# How can I audit git rerere's resolutions?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rerere

**Background**

I am currently resolving a merge conflict with git rerere enabled. `git status` shows one unmerged path. When I view the file, there are no `<<<<<<< HEAD` or `>>>>>>> <SHA>` markers identifying the conflict, which tells me that rerere has done it's work and resolved the conflict according to how I have done it in the past.

I would like to confirm that rerere's resolutions are correct.

The merge process I am working on is very complex involving multiple remotes contributing to the Linux kernel. I did a test merge of several remotes yesterday with the goal of identifying conflicts, notifying maintainers, then discarding the resulting (surely broken) kernel. While doing so, I made a couple of careless conflict resolutions just to move on to the next remote, and called `git rerere forget <pathspec>` on all of the conflicting paths after I was done, including the one I'm dealing with now. Since I told rerere to forget this path, I don't know why it resolved anything on this run, and I'm concerned that it applied the fix that I made yesterday when I didn't care if the result was correct.

**The Question**

Is there any way to see what conflicts rerere resolved after it has already applied the resolution?

I would like to avoid restarting the merge because it's a long process that we don't have fully automated yet. Also, since I tried to tell rerere to forget this path yesterday and yet it still applied a resolution today, I think I would just end up in the same position if I don't find out why `git rerere forget <pathspec>` failed first.

**Related Questions**
[Undo a git rerere resolution that was done in a rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18500016/2615940)  <-- solution requires restarting merge
[Are there any downsides to enabling git rerere?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5519244/2615940) <-- only discusses `git rerere forget <pathspec>`

**Follow Up Note/Question**
I just tried entering `git rerere forget` with no pathspec, which I'm aware is deprecated, but if I understand correctly, should make rerere forget all resolutions. I reran the merge and it still applied a resolution to the file. I also completely disabled rerere and ran the merge a third time so I could see the conflict, and rerere was indeed applying the half-hearted resolutions I did yesterday. Why is `forget` not correctly discarding resolution that I don't want to reuse?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can switch to the un-rerere'd merge result with

```
git checkout -m path/to/file
```

and then reapply it with

```
git rerere
```

Regarding the forget troubles, did you do the forget while the conflict was still active?  Forget applies to "the current conflict in <pathspec>"

> ```
> $ git checkout master^1
> Warning: you are leaving 1 commit behind, not connected to
> any of your branches:
>
>
>   9e2db79 test3
>
> HEAD is now at ca1fca7... Make a change to file (on master)
> $ git merge master^2
> Auto-merging file.txt
> CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file.txt
> Resolved 'file.txt' using previous resolution.
> Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
> $ git rerere forget file.txt
> Updated preimage for 'file.txt'
> Forgot resolution for file.txt
> $ vi file.txt                     # old resolution's still in the worktree
> $ git checkout -m file.txt        # now it's gone there too
> ```

Comment: You're my hero for the day.

Comment: Huh. Weird. I do `git merge ...`, which results in `conflict <path>` and `resolved <path> using previous resolution`. Then I do `git rerere forget <path>` on that resolved path. The command emits `error: no remembered resolution for <path>`.