# rerere: how to view original conflict after `autoresolution`?

Tags: git, git-rerere

After merging I get next log:

```
git merge --no-ff feature/seamless_registration 
Auto-merging cpanfile
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in cpanfile
Auto-merging bin/myapp
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in bin/myapp
Resolved 'bin/myapp' using previous resolution.
Resolved 'cpanfile' using previous resolution.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

After this I can view how this merge conflicts are resolved:

```
$git diff cpanfile
...
```

But how can I view original merge conflict?

`man git rerere` seems has no such command

Comment: Might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21635422/116923

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout -m cpanfile` should return the file to pre-conflict-resolution state

Comment: I do not want to view original file. I want to view merge conflict before auto resolution.