# git-rerere-forget does not forget previous recording

Tags: git

Here's the behavior of what I am seeing when I use `git rerere forget <path>`:

```
$ git merge origin/foo
Auto-merging foo.txt
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in foo.txt
Resolved 'foo.txt' using previous resolution.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

$ git rerere forget foo.txt
error: no remembered resolution for 'foo.txt'
```

I expected `git rerere forget foo.txt` to not emit an error and succeed.

Aborting the merge, and re-executing it, results in the same behavior.

Similar posts:

- [How can I audit git rerere's resolutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37887739/2630028)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21635422/2630028

Anyone have any insight on this?

**EDIT**:

Here's some added context:

```
user@host MINGW64 ~/git_rerere_test/foo (master)
$ git config rerere.enabled true

user@host MINGW64 ~/git_rerere_test/foo (master)
$ git merge conflict
Auto-merging foo.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in foo.txt
Recorded preimage for 'foo.txt'
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

user@host MINGW64 ~/git_rerere_test/foo (master|MERGING)
$ git checkout --ours foo.txt
Updated 1 path from the index

user@host MINGW64 ~/git_rerere_test/foo (master|MERGING)
$ git add -u

user@host MINGW64 ~/git_rerere_test/foo (master|MERGING)
$ git commit
Recorded resolution for 'foo.txt'.
[master 90fb0f6] Merge branch 'conflict'

user@host MINGW64 ~/git_rerere_test/foo (master)
$ git reset --hard HEAD~1
HEAD is now at bd8d1d5 foo

user@host MINGW64 ~/git_rerere_test/foo (master)
$ git merge conflict
Auto-merging foo.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in foo.txt
Resolved 'foo.txt' using previous resolution.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

user@host MINGW64 ~/git_rerere_test/foo (master|MERGING)
$ git rerere forget foo.txt
error: no remembered resolution for 'foo.txt'
```

Git (git-bash for windows) version is

```
$ git --version
git version 2.44.0.windows.1
```

When I try the same on a WSL Ubuntu shell:

```
user@host ~/knavero/git_rerere_test/foo
 % git config rerere.enabled
true

user@host ~/knavero/git_rerere_test/foo
 % git merge conflict
Auto-merging foo.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in foo.txt
Recorded preimage for 'foo.txt'
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

user@host ~/knavero/git_rerere_test/foo
 % git checkout --ours foo.txt

user@host ~/knavero/git_rerere_test/foo
 % git add foo.txt

user@host ~/knavero/git_rerere_test/foo
 % git commit
Recorded resolution for 'foo.txt'.
[master 6251d0c] Merge branch 'conflict'

user@host ~/knavero/git_rerere_test/foo
 % git reset HEAD~1

user@host ~/knavero/git_rerere_test/foo
 % git merge conflict
Auto-merging foo.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in foo.txt
Resolved 'foo.txt' using previous resolution.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

user@host ~/knavero/git_rerere_test/foo
 % git rerere forget foo.txt
Updated preimage for 'foo.txt'
Forgot resolution for foo.txt
```

Works as expected.

Git version in WSL Ubuntu:

```
 % git --version
git version 2.17.1
```

**EDIT 2:**

Here's an attempt using 2.44.0.windows.1 starting from a newly initialized repo, the directory contents of the repo is empty, and .git/rr-cache is starting clean (does not exist):

```
user@host MINGW64 ~/rerere_test
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/user/rerere_test/.git/

user@host MINGW64 ~/rerere_test (master)
$ touch foo.txt

user@host MINGW64 ~/rerere_test (master)
$ git add foo.txt

user@host MINGW64 ~/rerere_test (master)
$ git commit -m "foo.txt created"
[master (root-commit) d236343] foo.txt created
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 foo.txt

user@host MINGW64 ~/rerere_test (master)
$ git checkout -b conflict
Switched to a new branch 'conflict'

user@host MINGW64 ~/rerere_test (conflict)
$ echo conflict > foo.txt

user@host MINGW64 ~/rerere_test (conflict)
$ git add foo.txt
warning: in the working copy of 'foo.txt', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it

user@host MINGW64 ~/rerere_test (conflict)
$ git commit -m "edited foo.txt"
[conflict 78b1228] edited foo.txt
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

user@host MINGW64 ~/rerere_test (conflict)
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'

user@host MINGW64 ~/rerere_test (master)
$ echo master > foo.txt

user@host MINGW64 ~/rerere_test (master)
$ git add foo.txt
warning: in the working copy of 'foo.txt', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it

user@host MINGW64 ~/rerere_test (master)
$ git commit -m "foo.txt"
[master 19ecc03] foo.txt
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

user@host MINGW64 ~/rerere_test (master)
$ git config rerere.enabled true

user@host MINGW64 ~/rerere_test (master)
$ git merge conflict
Auto-merging foo.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in foo.txt
Recorded preimage for 'foo.txt'
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

user@host MINGW64 ~/rerere_test (master|MERGING)
$ git checkout --ours foo.txt
Updated 1 path from the index

user@host MINGW64 ~/rerere_test (master|MERGING)
$ git add foo.txt

user@host MINGW64 ~/rerere_test (master|MERGING)
$ git commit
Recorded resolution for 'foo.txt'.
[master d0c2b8e] Merge branch 'conflict'

user@host MINGW64 ~/rerere_test (master)
$ git reset --hard HEAD~1
HEAD is now at 19ecc03 foo.txt

user@host MINGW64 ~/rerere_test (master)
$ git merge conflict
Auto-merging foo.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in foo.txt
Resolved 'foo.txt' using previous resolution.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

user@host MINGW64 ~/rerere_test (master|MERGING)
$ git rerere forget foo.txt
error: no remembered resolution for 'foo.txt'
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce. `git rerere forget` works as expected for me. I suggest to inspect the conflicted state: `git checkout -m foo.txt`. Rerere depends on the textual representation of file with conflict markers. Perhaps there is something strange in the file?

Comment: hm, I think I might be using `git rerere forget` wrong. If I'm trying to do `git rerere forget <path>` does the merge context (`ours` and `theirs` branch pair) have to be the exact same as when I had recorded the previous resolution? In my above example, I'm merging `origin/foo` into the current branch, but when I had previously resolved `foo.txt`, it was recorded over a merge where the `ours` branch was different, but the `theirs` branch was the same.

Comment: Yes, the conflicted state must be exactly that of original conflict. But in the command sequence above, including the shown ouput `Resolved ... using previous resolution` this condition would be satisfied. Then the immediately following rerere command should work as expected and forget the resolution (and that even though the actual file already contains the resolved state; rerere is able to use information provided in the index file to reconstruct the conflicted state).

Comment: added some more information

Comment: Perhaps let us know the contents of foo.txt that are conflicting.

Comment: Settings about EOF handling may out-wit rerere.

Comment: `foo.txt` contains one line on branch `master`: "foo\n". `foo.txt` contains one line on branch `conflict`: "conflict\n". The minimal reproduction repo contains a total of 3 commits.

Comment: That's exactly the situation the command sequence in my answer sets up. I just tried it again with only one line, `seq 1` instead of `seq 5` and `1s,$,x,` resp. `y` to set up the confict, it works fine. There's something else going on here. Instead of characterizing the evidence you're looking at, *show* it. If we try what you say and it doesn't happen, there's something you overlooked.

Comment: @jthill, please see "EDIT 2". Is that what you mean by "show it"?

Comment: Yes, that was enough to eliminate a lot of possibilities, site defaults though I don't know what could produce this is what's left, see the conversation after my "answer" showing my own attempt at reproducing.

Answer (score 1):

Got it: your reproduction steps shows

```
$ git add foo.txt
warning: in the working copy of 'foo.txt', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
```

so you've got `core.autocrlf` or some equivalent set by default, `foo.txt` is winding up with `eol=crlf` and `text` attributes. That's what leads to rerere forget getting confused: somewhere in its checks it's not applying the eol transform but checkout and merge (and the main rerere handling) are.

```bash
sh -x <<\EOD
rm -rf rereretest; git init $_; cd $_; 
git config rerere.enabled true
git config core.autocrlf false  # change to true and `git rerere forget` gets confused
echo >foo; git add .;    git commit -am init
git checkout -b conflict
echo conflict >foo;      git commit -am conflict
git checkout master
echo master >foo;        git commit -am master
git merge conflict; git checkout --ours foo; git commit -am resolve

git reset --hard @~
git merge conflict
git rerere forget foo
EOD
```

Comment: Does this in some way answer a question?

Comment: @j6t it shows that the steps OP gives don't reproduce the stated problem.

Comment: I've appended information to the initial post that lists commands starting from a newly initialized repo and where .git/rr-cache does not exist. LMK if I can add more information, but I'm not sure I can be any more clear in the reproduction steps. I guess whatever the behavior is, has nothing to do with the git-version.

Comment: Yep, I just ran your  command sequence (a `sh -x <<\EOD` / `EOD` wrapper makes such things easily c&p-able and reviewable) and it works fine. Tried it again with a bare template (`--template=''`), it works fine.  Try adding a `--template=''` arg to the `git init` to see if there's some hinky setup in your config, also try, from your work tree tip, `grep -r . .` to show the contents of all text files which will include the config and any hooks your template sets up).

Comment: Also, `git config --get-regexp .` will list all config items in effect whatever the source.

Comment: Just read the edits WRT `core.autocrlf`. Thanks for making that observation and commenting on it. I think, for now, I'll stop using git-rerere-forget. I need `core.autocrlf` more than I do `git-rerere-forget`. Maybe it's worth reporting on the git-for-windows issue page though. This was a good start either way.